# Количество страниц для пагинации Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, pagination

Подскажите пожалуйста, как ограничить колличество страниц доступных для пагинации. Т.е. есть какие-то входные параметры, по которым мы делаем ваборку. В результате у нас получается допустим 1000 записей. На одной странице выводится 10 записей, таким образом всего выходит 100 страниц. Как сделать, чтобы было доступно только 20 страниц. Не могу понять, толи нужно что-то указать в QueryBuilder`е, толи в ActiveDataProvider`e, толи в Pager`e. Не могу нагуглить, как подобное реализуется. Наверно потому что не могу правильно сформировать вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по **[докам](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html#$maxButtonCount-detail)** за это отвечает `pager`, у которого есть поле `maxButtonCount`

Пример с `GridView`

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summaryOptions' => ['class' =>'dfenx_pagination_summary',],
    'pager' => ['options' => ['class' => 'pagination pull-right']],
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'pager' => [
        'maxButtonCount'=>3,  // вот тут количество кнопок
        ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
```

ну или если отдельно

```
echo LinkPager::widget([
    ...
    'maxButtonCount' => 3,
    ...
]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вы не совсем правильно меня поняли. maxButtonCount отвечает за количество кнопок в пагинаторе, а мне нужно ограничить количество страниц. Т.е. грубо говоря, точно указать номер страницы, которая будет последней.

Comment: @Andrey ограничивай `pagination` значит. К примеру вот описание http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html ... там есть запрос `Article::find()->where(['status' => 1])` .... вот если у тебя будет запрос такой, то там дописываешь `limit` который равен `максимальному числу страниц * количество записей на странице` и всё...... вот она основная формула......

Comment: при использовании ActiveDataProvider'a, как я понимаю, параметр $query->limit($n) переписывается на то, что указано в $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize, а потому такой подход не работает. Или я не правильно понимаю, где limit еще нужно прописать.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, нашел ответ. Нужно было для ActiveDataProvider'a указывать свойство totalCount.

Comment: @Andrey ну да (это как раз в примере по ссылке есть), но он устанавливается путем `$query->count()`, где `query` - это запрос к БД. А в бд, как раз будет запрос с лимитом, который я написал выше (на случай, если изменятся параметры вывода на страницу и будет хотеться вывести не 20 страниц а другое числов)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ. Как правильно подсказали, это называется "Ограничение pagination". Нужно было просто для ActiveDataProvider'a прописать для свойство totalCount значение равное "количество записей на странице * максимальное число страниц".
Спасибо за помощь.